# Check if word file is open with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have an application that generates documents.

However if a document is already open, then the generated new document cannot override the opened document, so no changes occur.

How can I properly check whether the document is already open or not? (And if open, then close it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
 If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\~$MyWordDocument.doc") Then
   MsgBox("File is open")
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Also check [FAQ: How do I check whether a file is in use?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dead0507-06f5-43e0-9250-a78437956bc8/faq-how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-is-in-use?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: Thank you, it almost worked! 
It is a smart one to check on the ~$ for the temp word file!

I only did not need the Application.StartupPath & to control for this.

Answer (score 3):

This code is working for me

```
Public Function FileInUse(ByVal sFile As String) As Boolean
     Dim thisFileInUse As Boolean = False
     If System.IO.File.Exists(sFile) Then
         Try
           Using f As New IO.FileStream(sFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
                    ' thisFileInUse = False
           End Using
         Catch
           thisFileInUse = True
         End Try
     End If
     Return thisFileInUse
    End Function
```

Comment: This is also a nice option!